# How to make a Spring WebSocket which retains its message history?

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, sockjs

I am trying to build a Spring WebSocket which would successfully retain the previous messages sent in the WebSocket.

Example of the successful concept:

```
Browser 1:

CHAT
TestUser: Hi
TestUser2: Bye 

Browser 2 (Which was started after both messages were sent):

CHAT
TestUser: Hi
TestUser2: Bye
// The messages above were loaded upon connection, because the WebSocket had retained them some how.
```

Currently I have the following:

```
Browser 1:

CHAT
TestUser: Hi
TestUser2: Bye 

Browser 2 (Which was started after both messages were sent):

CHAT
// Nothing...
```

I want to know how to implement the Spring WebSocket to load this properly?

Comment: Store the messages in a table?

Comment: Sure, but how would I make it load previous messages, etc.

Comment: Read from the db

Comment: That part is clear, the issue lies in sending the Browser 2 the data upon connection

Answer (score 0):

You could save add every message sent by users into a static `List<CustomObject>`, where `CustomObject` holds all datas about message (it can be a JSON or a simple object with few attributes) and set a method to run at the start of new connection to send to client every message sent so far (overriding method `afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session)` from `TextWebSocketHandler` if Spring).